# popup window gets opened in small size unless changing the security settings in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am using IE 8 I have the following javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function popupWindow(url) {
  w = 1026;
  h = 760;
  var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
  var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
  window.location.href="/site/testApps#app=testApp&nav=testNav";
  var newWindow = window.open(url, 'windowname', "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no,   
  status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+',   
  top='+top+',left='+left',screenY='+top+', screenX='+left'");
}
</script>
```

the pop up is opening successfully, But the problem is it is opening with smaller size. 
i fixed this by changing the security settings in IE as shown below.

[image]

Can anyone shed light on why this happened? and what is the solution for this problem? with out changing security settings in IE?

**UPDATE:**
we have different environments (dev,test and uat(runs on secure porthttps://)). this issue is happening only if we run with https://
this is working well(the pop up window is opening with proper dimensions) in dev and test env.

Comment: something to do with `"…top='+top+',left='+left',screenY='+top+', screenX='+left'"` as in the `'`'s should be `"`? or change the outer quotes from `"`'s to `'`'s?

Comment: Please show the code from `/myURL here`. Changing the `href` will load a new page, and anything after `window.location.href` is not executed on the original page. Also the variables of the old page are gone.

Comment: @Teemu /site/apps#app=myApp&nav=testNav

Comment: Ehh.. I mean the code in that file. The code you've posted can't open the pop-up, it must come from another page.

Comment: @Teemu <a href="/myPage.jsp?redirect=none" onclick="popupWindow(this.href);return false;">&nbsp;CLICK</a>

Comment: @Teemu edited the question. sorry for confusion. :) this is in single page. not from different pages

Comment: I can't imagine anything after line `window.location.href="/myURL here";` could be executed. It loads a new page.

Answer (score 2):

If it is not necessary to have a new window, I suggest using 'internal popups' (e.g. a large DIV with an iframe inside it). You can let jQuery assign all anchors with a specific classname to get opened in the internal popup.

A great benefit is that it's cross-browser, privacy settings independent and fully stylable.

This also works great against popupkillers, since there is no real popup to detect.

Simple example:

```js
$("a.internal-popup").click(function() {
  
  // load href-URL in iframe
  $("#popup-iframe").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
  
  // show popup-DIV
  $("#popup-frame").show();
  
  // prevent the original click
  return false;
  
});
```

```html
<a href="site.html" class="internal-popup">Link</a>

<div id="popup-frame">
<iframe src="" id="popup-iframe" name="popup-iframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

Don't forget to add a close button in the popup DIV

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/PhilQ/ctnqk1Lb/

Answer (score 1):

try changing the following

```
var newWindow = window.open(myURL, 'windowname', "toolbar=no, location=no,
directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes,
copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+',left='+left',
screenY='+top+', screenX='+left'");
```

to the following because the variables aren't used instead they are rendered literally as `top='+top+'`

```
var newWindow = window.open(myURL, 'windowname', "toolbar=no, location=no,
directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes,
copyhistory=no, width=" + w + ", height=" + h + ", top=" + top + ",
left=" + left + ", screenY=" + top + ", screenX=" + left);
```

also you can notice in that the color of the variables is back and not red for indication of text like the original one.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for the popup to open

```
jQuery(".Popup").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 385, width: 580,
    minheight: 165, minwidth: 460,
    modal: false,
    buttons: {
        "Close": function () {
            jQuery(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

and call this `jQuery` function:

```
jQuery(".Popup").dialog("open")
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the issue is that the setting "Allow script-initiated windows without size or position constraints" is disabled by default in IE8.

Go to Internet Options | Security Tab | Internet - click on the "Custom" button then scroll to the Miscellaneous section. See the option "Allow script-initiated windows without size or position constraints". When this is set to disabled, any link that calls a JavaScript function that opens a new window will not be able to resize or position the pop-up window.

Change this setting to "Enable" and the window will resize and position correctly.

Answer (score 0):

### Implicit Globals

your w and h variables are set as globals. change those to lines to:

```
var w = 1026;
var h = 760;
```

### Order of operation

Your code sets `window.location.href`prior to the `newWindow = window.open()` call, depending on the specific win/ie environment, anything after setting the location.href value may have unpredictable results.
**instead:**

```
var newWindow = window.open(...);
window.location.href = "...";
```

### String Concatenation issue:

In the third argument to window.open, you started the string with a double-quote, then went to escape it with single-quotes. Use this instead, do not include CRLF's in the actual string:

```
window.open('about:blank', 'windowname', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no,
    status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, copyhistory=no, 
    width='+ w +', height='+ h +', top='+ top +',left='+ left +',
    screenY='+ top +', screenX='+ left
);
```

### IE Security

Because popups were (and still are) so widely abused, IE may ignore some window parameters when using `window.open()`.

- [MSDN window.open method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536651(v=vs.85).aspx)

  - See, "Return Values" Section, and, "Remarks."
- [MSDN Understanding Protected Mode in IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bb250462(v=vs.85).aspx)
- See all 3 bullets in, "Introducing Protected Mode."